# How Can I Restore The Greeter (From Unity Greeter to Pantheon Greeter)?

Tags: release-freya, greeter

The lockscreen I get:
[image]

How do I get the standard lock screen back?

Comment: bug? I don't think its a bug.

Comment: please try my answer and let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have `unity-greeter` installed on Freya.

So remove it with the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-greeter
```

If you install unity desktop over Freya, light-locker will be removed.

So install `light-locker` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install light-locker
```

Now reboot - this is required.